# Printing without javascript modifications

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with a tab view that is controlled via javascript. With JS disabled, the tabs align vertically under each other. In document.ready a function is called that rearanges the tabs to be over each other so you have to click on the tab header to display the content.

When I call window.print the elements are not shown like they would be without javascript but are over each other what is suboptimal for a paper version of the website.

Is there another way or do I have to rearrange the items back to what they would look like without JS prior to calling window.print ?

EDIT:
In general it works like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.btn1').click(function()
    {
       $('.tile2').css('display', 'none');
       $('.tile1').css('display', 'block');
    });
    $('.btn2').click(function()
    {
       $('.tile1').css('display', 'none');
       $('.tile2').css('display', 'block');
    });
    $('.tile2').css('display', 'none');                  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MK77j/

Comment: Give us some code please. HTML, JS and CSS

Answer (score 2):

Use a print css to override the JS applied styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```